# Cannot save .m3u8 file to gallery in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying save.m3u8 file to gallery but its not working , here In my code I'm trying to convert to mp4 and saving it

```
Dio dio = Dio();
        try {
          var dir="/storage/emulated/0/Download/MYVideos";
          if (Platform.isAndroid) {
            dir = "/storage/emulated/0/Download/MYVideos";
          } else {
            dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
          }
          await dio.download(videoUrl, "{$dir}/myvideo.mp4",
              onReceiveProgress: (rec, total) {
              
             
              });
        } catch (e) {
          print(e);
        }
```

Comment: can you send error log please @Arun Lazer

Comment: I can download a MP4 file with 6kb but it's not opening . No error I'm facing I can't download the perfect file

Comment: Hey @ArunLazer, did you find any solution to this problem? I also need to download .m3u8 files locally and access them later for offline viewing.